# Use a static Java declaration in macro implementation

Tags: scala, scala-macros, scala-macro-paradise

I am trying to use a static method on a Java class, `T`, in a macro implementation:

```
def macroImpl[T : c.WeakTypeTag](c: Context): c.Expr[ResultType] = {
  import c.universe._
  val tpe = weakTypeOf[T]
  val someStaticMethod = tpe.declaration(c.universe.newTermName("someStaticMethod")).asMethod
  c.Expr[ResultType] { q""" new ResultType {
    def myMethod = ${someStaticMethod.name.toTermName}  
  }"""}
}
```

This does not work. When I print out all the members and declarations of `tpe`, the static methods that I want to use are not there. How do I access these static methods and use them in the quasiquote?

I am using version 2.1.0 of the macro-paradise compiler plugin for scala 2.10.6.

Comment: Static methods are modeled as methods on the companion object.

Comment: @som-snytt How do I get to the companion?  It looks like in the 2.11 API I can do `tpe.companion` but I am using 2.10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After seeing @som-snytt's comment, I investigated how to access the companion object. The code ended up looking something like this:

```
def macroImpl[T : c.WeakTypeTag](c: Context): c.Expr[ResultType] = {
  import c.universe._
  val tpe = weakTypeOf[T]
  val companion = tpe.typeSymbol.companionSymbol
  c.Expr[ResultType] { q""" new ResultType {
    def myMethod = ${companion.name.toTermName}.someStaticMethod  
  }"""}
}
```

I look up the companion symbol and then call the method `someStaticMethod` on it in the quasiquote. This seems to do what I want.

I can get the declarations of `companion` by doing `companion.typeSignature.declarations`